# How MySql Serializable locking works

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to understand how next-key locking works with serializable isolation level in MySql 5.6.

There are next explanation in documentation:

> "SELECT ... FROM is a consistent read, reading a snapshot of the database and setting no locks unless the transaction isolation level is set to SERIALIZABLE. For SERIALIZABLE level, the search sets shared next-key locks on the index records it encounters. However, only an index record lock is required for statements that lock rows using a unique index to search for a unique row."

So, If I have next table:

```
table simple2
(
    id int primary key,
    val int,
    index (val)
);


insert into simple2 values (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(5,5),(7,7),(15,15);
```

Then:

Transaction 1:

```
set transaction isolation level serializable;
start transaction;
select * from simple2 where val = 7;
```

Transaction 2:

```
set transaction isolation level serializable;
start transaction;
insert into simple2 values (10, 10); //blocked
```

**I don't understand why I can't add (10,10).**

Because, according to doc explanation, **only row index and gap before index should be blocked by Transaction 1: (5, 7].**

Comment: I'm not sure if MySQL uses index with so few records. It may simply do a full table scan locking all rows. Explain and innodb status monitor are your friends.

Comment: MySql doesn't lock the whole table in this case - it's possible to add (4,4), since index (val) it's out of gap (5,7] which is blocked, according to documentation.